# Print last character from word from char array

Tags: c, arrays

I'v got this:

```
char file_name[50];
strncpy(file_name, dp2->d_name, sizeof(file_name2));
// put some words in it, for example "E348C", "E348", "E348A"......
```

And I need to find last character from each word and check it later if it is number or letter..... but the words as you can see have not the same length....

I have no idea how to get last character...

Also char the variable file_name[50]; could be defined as char * file_name; I don't care....

Any ideas ?

Comment: You *do* know about the `strlen` function? And also remember that arrays are indexed from `0` to `length - 1`.

Comment: Oh, and you have to be careful, as `strncpy` will not add the terminating `'\0'` character in the destination if the source is too long. So you have to get the length of first the source, and then *maybe* the length of the destination.

Comment: I hope noone posts a complete solution. In this case a couple of hints and tips should be enough and will help the OP more than the full solution in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about strlen() ... thanks for reminding it... I'll try :)

Comment: @Joachim Pilebrog: as I said, it doesnt metter if I define file_name as char * instead of char[] ..so I can try char * file_name; and just file_name = dp2->d_name; what you thing...???

Comment: It depends entirely what you are doing with the string. If you want to modify the string, then it might be better to use e.g. `strdup`. Otherwise just using the pointer should work fine (as long as you don't free what it points to from somewhere else). And remember that certain string functions (for example `strtok`) *do* modify the string you pass them.

Comment: well, strlen() works fine so far with string ( char*) ...thanks guys..

Comment: well, yeah but and how can I get (return) or print the value of the character from string? If it was array, I'll do it with for() but since I use char* ...I have no idea... (remind I use C, not C++)...

Comment: Ok, I solve this already.. thanks everybody

Comment: Please do not write an answer in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: It seems that the question has already been solved in the comments above, but maybe somebody comes along with a similar question in the future...

Please look at the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char file_name[50];

    char inp[] = "something3";

    strncpy(file_name, inp, sizeof(inp));

    printf("%s\n", file_name);

    // strlen returns the length of a string. 
    char end_char = file_name[strlen(file_name)-1];

    printf("%c\n", end_char);

    if (isdigit(end_char)) {     // checks if end_char is a number
        printf("last character is a number\n");
    } 
    if (isalpha(end_char)){      // checks if end_char is a letter
        printf("last character is a character\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Sample output for `inp[] = "something3"`:

```
something3
3
last character is a number
```

Sample output for `inp[] = "somethingX"`:

```
somethingX
X
last character is a character
```